# Connecting multiple database using Spring with Bonecp

Tags: spring

Am developing an application, where in users has to login to the application by giving username , password and selecting business unit.
                   Based on business unit, the application has to connect to the respective database. How can this be achieved in spring with bonecp or spring jdbc template ? Considering performance which should I choose spring with bonecp or spring jdbc template